# Is this theorem an extension of Scheffé Lemma

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Let $\nu_n(A)=\int_A f_n d\mu$ and $\nu(A)=\int_A f d\mu$ where $f_n, f$ are density functions. If $\nu_n(X)=\nu(X)$ and $f_n\to f$ ($\mu$- a.e) then $$\sup\limits_{A\in \mathcal A}|\nu_n(A)-\nu(A)|=\frac12 \int_X |f_n-f|d\mu \to 0, as\quad n\to \infty.$$

It looks like Scheffe' Lemma  but I am not sure. Does anyone know this theorem and what textbook contains it? Or maybe give me some hints for the proof. Thanks 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%E2%80%99s_lemma

Comment: The convergence to $0$ is just Scheffes Lemma (if $\nu_n (X)<\infty$). The first identity is not too hard to see.

Answer (score 2):

This is just rote application of definitions. The first equality comes from the definition of total variation by picking sets on which the two measures differ. You can verify it by proving $\leq$ and $\geq$. The convergence of the integral to 0 is dominated convergence. First observe that

$$\int_X |f_n-f|=\int_X [f_n-f]_+d\mu-\int [f_n-f]_-d\mu=\int_{X_+}(f_n-f)d\mu-\int_{X_-}(f-f_n)d\mu=\int_X f-\int_Xf_n=1-1=0.$$

Then since $[f-f_n]_+\leq f$, dominated convergence gives

$$\int_X |f_n-f|d\mu\leq 2\int_{X^+}[f_n-f]_+d\mu \rightarrow 0$$