# $L^1$ convergence kernel convolutions implies weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, weak-convergence

I was reading a paper where they claim the following. Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the space of measures on compact $\mathfrak{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi(\cdot - \theta)$ be the normal kernel with location $\theta$:

$$ f_P(x) = \int \phi (x - \theta) dP(\theta)$$

**They claim the following:**

The map $P \mapsto f_{P}$ is one-to-one, onto $\mathscr{F}$, where $\mathscr{F}=\left\{f_{P}: P \in \mathscr{M}\right\}$. Further $P_n \rightarrow P_0$ weakly if and only if $\left\|f_{P_n}-f_{P_0}\right\|_1 \rightarrow 0$.

For the part abount injectivity I found solution here: [Is "Convolution operator" well-defined and injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3963664/is-convolution-operator-well-defined-and-injective)

Clearly, by the definition of $\mathscr{F}$ it is also onto. So on this part I agree. For the direction $\Rightarrow$ the claim follows upon noticing that the Gaussian kernel in one variable is bounded Lipschitz continuous (see [Is the Gaussian density Lipschitz continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3630967/is-the-gaussian-density-lipschitz-continuous)). Then an application of Portmanteau's Lemma yields for any fixed $x$:

$$ \int \phi dP_n \rightarrow \int \phi dP_0$$

Then using again the boundedness of the kernels and nonnegativity of our integrals, an application of Dominated Convergence Theorem yields: $\left\|f_{P_n}-f_{P_0}\right\|_1 \rightarrow 0$.

Now for the other direction, I am stuck. I tried to use Scheffe's Lemma to use later the Portmanteau's Lemma with the classical convergence $P_n \rightarrow P_0$ weakly iff $P_n(\theta) \rightarrow P_0 (\theta)$ at all continuity points $\theta$. Indeed the application of Scheffe's Lemma gives from $\left\|f_{P_n}-f_{P_0}\right\|_1 \rightarrow 0$ that:

$$\int \int \phi(x-\theta) dP_n(\theta) dx \rightarrow \int \int \phi(x-\theta) dP_0(\theta) dx$$

Then one could use Fubini's Theorem and the fact that for fixed $\theta$ it holds: $\int \phi(x-\theta) dx = 1$ since it is a Gaussian Kernel. However, it doesn't give the claim eventually.

I also tried to argue by contradiction but I did not manage to get anywhere useful. I also tried to use this knowledge:
[Is this theorem an extension of Scheffé Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392127/is-this-theorem-an-extension-of-scheff%C3%A9-lemma)

Maybe you will find it helpful.

**Q: Do you have any idea on how to tackle this problem? Or any reference that I could consult?**

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: I agree on the fact that convergence in $L^1$ of the convultions $\gamma \star P_n \stackrel{L^1}{\rightarrow} \gamma \star P_0$ implies convergence in probability and thus also weak convergence. However I got a bit lost with the part of the Fourier transform, could you argue a bit more please?

Comment: The Fourier transform of a probability measure is usually known as its characteristic function. As you may remember from probability theory, weak convergence of (finite )measures is equivalent to convergence of their characteristic functions (Lévy-Bochner theorem)

Comment: Yes, I just don't remember why the convergence of $\hat{\gamma} \hat{P}_n \rightarrow \hat{\gamma} \hat{P}_0$ implies $\hat{P}_n \rightarrow \hat{P}_0$. By the way, you might want to post your answer so I can give you points.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer looks correct to me. If you want to post it properly below, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Phi$ denote the standard normal distribution and by $\phi$ its density (w.r.t. Lebesgue's measure). For any probability measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $f_P=\int \phi(x-y) P(dy)$ is the density function (w.r.t Lenesgue's measure) of the measure $\Phi*P$.

If $\|f_n-f_0\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ then for any bounded continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $\Big|\int g(f_n-f_0)\,dx\Big|\leq\|g\|_\infty\|f_n-f_0\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. This shows that $\Phi*P_n$ converges weakly to $\Phi*P_0$. Taking the Fourier transform $\widehat{\Phi}\hat{P_n}$ converges to $\widehat{\Phi}\hat{P_0}$ poitwise and so, $\hat{P_n}$ converges to $\hat{P_0}$ poitwise. This implies that  $P_n$ converges to $P_0$ weakly.

Conversely, if $P_n$ converges weakly to $P$, then as  $\phi$ of the  is bounded and continuous, it follows that
$$f_n(x)=\int \phi(x-y)P_n(dy)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int \phi(y) P_0(dy)=f_0(y)$$
The functions $f_n$ and $f_0$ are the density functions of the measures $\Phi*P_n$ and $\Phi*P_0$ respectively and thus. Scheffé's theorem then implies that
$\|f_n-f_0\|_1=\|\Phi*P_n-\Phi*P_0\|_{TV}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.